I represent many products in view but the return of all them in controller is the first product I use ASP.NET Core 6 MVC
I represent many projects correctly but It's return the same object in controller specifically the first item in database
In controller:
public IActionResult AddToBasket(ProductsModel products)
{
    if (AuthController.user != null)
    {
        using Data data = new Data();

        int id = data.products.Where(x => x.Name == products.Name && x.Price == products.Price && x.Discription == products.Discription).ToList()[0].Id;

        data.basket.Add(new BasketModel { Amount = products.Amount, AccountId = AuthController.user.Id, ProductId = id });
        data.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Products");
    }
}

In the view, I have this markup:
<form method="post" asp-action="AddToBasket" asp-controller="Products" style="width:100%;">
    @foreach(ProductsModel pro in ViewBag.prod)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12" style="float:right;">
            <div class="beds_section active">
                <input readonly="readonly" class="bed_text" value="@pro.Name" style="border:none;" asp-for="Name">
                <div><img src="../@pro.Img" class="image_2"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Add to Basket" style="float:right;" name="input"/> 
                <input type="number" placeholder="amount" asp-for="Amount" value="1" min="1" max="@pro.Amount" style="width:80px;float:right; width:80px;" /> 
                <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
                <input style="border:none; width:150px;" readonly="readonly" value="@pro.Price" asp-for="Price" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input style="border:none; width:100%; height:100%;"  readonly="readonly" value="@pro.Discription" asp-for="Discription">
            </div> 
        </div>
}
</form>

It's seems all product share same asp-for.
How to solve it this first time I use stack overflow may my question isn't clear 

Could you please share the ProductsModel makeup?


I represent many projects correctly but It's return the same object in controller specifically the first item in database

If you check the request that you made to add to basket in F12 dev tool network tab, you would find the data look like below.


It's seems all product share same asp-for.

As you mentioned, the name attribute of input fileds' in your form with same value, which cause the issue.
To fix the issue and add expected product item to basket, you can try to modify the code to separate product item into <form> as below.
@foreach (ProductsModel pro in ViewBag.prod)
{
    <form method="post" asp-action="AddToBasket" asp-controller="home" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12" style="float:right;">
            <div class="beds_section active">
                <input readonly="readonly" class="bed_text" value="@pro.Name" style="border:none;" asp-for="Name">
                <div><img src="../@pro.Img" class="image_2"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Add to Basket" style="float:right;" name="input" />
                <input type="number" placeholder="amount" asp-for="Amount" value="1" min="1" max="@pro.Amount" style="width:80px;float:right; width:80px;" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
                <input style="border:none; width:150px;" readonly="readonly" value="@pro.Price" asp-for="Price" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input style="border:none; width:100%; height:100%;" readonly="readonly" value="@pro.Discription" asp-for="Discription">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
} 

